# Mailchimp Subscribe to newsletter using checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mailchimp

Anybody know here how to integrate to Mailchimp API script to HTML Bootstrap 3 form? I only want to know the code for the checkbox which will trigger if the user wants to get a newsletter upon signup.

This is my form

```
<form role="form" id="feedbackForm" method="POST">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="textinput">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your First Name"/>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your first name.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your Last Name"/>
          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your last name.</span>
        </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Email Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"/>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Company Name</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Enter your company name"/>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Message<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label for="selectbasic">How did you hear about us?</label>
                                                  <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Select</option>
                                                    <option value="Search Engine">Search engine</option>
                                                    <option value="Microsoft DPE">Microsoft DPE</option>
                                                    <option value="Microsoft Event">Microsoft event</option>
                                                    <option value="Social Media">Social media</option>
                                                    <option value="Word of Mouth">Word of mouth</option>
                                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" id="emailUpdates" name="emailUpdates" value="Yes"> Please keep me informed of kinectAPI product updates and news
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                              <img id="captcha" src="library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
                                              <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false" class="btn btn-green btn-sm">Show a Different Image</a><br/>
                                              <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha_code" id="captcha_code" placeholder="For security, please enter the code displayed in the box." />
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter the code displayed within the image.</span>
                                              </div>

                                              <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a the security code.</span>
                                           <button type="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-purple btn-md message-btn">Submit Message</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you want to subsrcibe to something when the user clicks on the checkbox?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you won't be able to use Bootstrap to create an HTML email. Also including a form in an email is a tricky path to go down to due the widely varying levels of support in email clients. Basically HTML emails need to be coded like it's 1998. You can make a responsive HTML email but using HTML's natural responsiveness with tables etc rather than trying to use an HTMl framework.

Comment: I want to create a subscribe to newsletter using mailchimp. someone who edit my title in my post.